# How long of an encrypted payment ID hex message can be sent after the v0.15 fork?

Tags: payment-id

With the recent v0.15 upgrade, as of 2019-Dec long payment IDs have been removed. The only one remaining now is an encrypted payment ID. If I wanted to convert this payment ID as an alphanumeric message, using hex, how long of a text message can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encrypted payment IDs are 8 bytes (16 hex chars).

Comment: In recent transaction 'extra' fields I have found two common pieces of data. The transaction public key, obviously, and something with tag = 2 and length = 9. I would presume that is a dummy encrypted payment ID. It is 9 bytes, not 8. What is the story there?

Comment: Tag 2 is for extra nonce, and has nothing to do with the size of an encrypted payment ID - the question.

Comment: Ok I see interesting. I will make a new question about this.